# What's the shortest code to cause a stack overflow?

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf

To commemorate the public launch of Stack Overflow, what's the shortest code to cause a stack overflow? Any language welcome.

ETA: Just to be clear on this question, seeing as I'm an occasional Scheme user: tail-call "recursion" is really iteration, and any solution which can be converted to an iterative solution relatively trivially by a decent compiler won't be counted. :-P

ETA2: I've now selected a “best answer”; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188/stack-overflow-code-golf/71833#71833) for rationale. Thanks to everyone who contributed! :-)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

All these answers and no Befunge? I'd wager a fair amount it's shortest solution of them all:

```
1
```

Not kidding. Try it yourself: http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html

EDIT: I guess I need to explain this one. The 1 operand pushes a 1 onto Befunge's internal stack and the lack of anything else puts it in a loop under the rules of the language.

Using the interpreter provided, you will eventually--and I mean *eventually*--hit a point where the Javascript array that represents the Befunge stack becomes too large for the browser to reallocate. If you had a simple Befunge interpreter with a smaller and bounded stack--as is the case with most of the languages below--this program would cause a more noticeable overflow faster.

Comment: Hmm … but is this really a stack overflow or just an infinite loop? My JS interpreter did *not* overflow, it just went on vacation, so to speak.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop, because the 1 instruction pushes a 1 onto the stack. Eventually, your Befunge interpreter will run out of stack space, but it'll take a while. :)

Comment: You.. crashed my browser and.. sent my CPU fan into overdrive.

Comment: Amazing! My computer or browser (Opera) didn't crash but both processors were running on 100% and the fan speed was at 3.

Comment: Here's a Befunge program that overflows faster:  `"`  It loads 79 copies of the number 32 every two times it wraps around, rather than 2 copies of the number 1.

Answer (score 291):

Read this line, and do what it says **twice**.

Answer (score 173):

You could also try this in C#.net

```
throw new StackOverflowException();
```

Comment: The pedant in me says it doesn't cause any stack to overflow, just throws an exception. That's like saying the quickest way to be attacked by sharks is to stand in the sea and scream "Shark attack!". Despite this, I will up-vote it. :)

Comment: Well - is there a difference? Can you catch it and continue? Or is it exactly like a stackoverflow in c#? In that case, it somehow is a stackoverflow, since it is indistinguishable from one... However - upvote for all the reasons above

Comment: If a stack overflows in the woods with nobody around to catch, does it throw an exception?

Comment: I wouldn't say the 'shortest' since it's not like you can compile a one-liner like that. It _does_ throw a stack overflow quickly though I guess.

Answer (score 159):

**Nemerle**:

This **crashes the compiler** with a StackOverflowException:

```
def o(){[o()]}
```

Answer (score 119):

My current best (in x86 assembly) is:

```
push eax
jmp short $-1
```

which results in 3 bytes of object code (`50 EB FD`). For 16-bit code, this is also possible:

```
call $
```

which also results in 3 bytes (`E8 FD FF`).

Comment: Counting the bytes after "compiling" (or assembling) is not code-golf.

Comment: The question says "[...] what's the shortest code to cause a stack overflow?" It doesn't specify source code, interpreted code, machine code, object code or managed code...

Comment: For the record, Shin's golf server allows you to send object code to be judged, although it will count all your ELF headers too. Hmm....

Comment: See, e.g., http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?FizzBuzz#x86 for some examples of this. (I honestly don't know how people can make 99-byte ELF binaries, though.) :-P

Comment: @lbrandy: There are enough people who can write object code directly. I can't do it for x86 but for a certain microprocessor I can. I'd count such code.

Answer (score 113):

### PIC18

The [PIC18 answer given by TK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188/stack-overflow-code-golf/62209#62209) results in the following instructions (binary):

```
overflow
   PUSH
   0000 0000 0000 0101
   CALL overflow
   1110 1100 0000 0000
   0000 0000 0000 0000
```

However, CALL alone will perform a stack overflow:

```
CALL $
1110 1100 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

### Smaller, faster PIC18

But RCALL (relative call) is smaller still (not global memory, so no need for the extra 2 bytes):

```
RCALL $
1101 1000 0000 0000
```

So the smallest on the PIC18 is a single instruction, 16 bits (two bytes).  This would take 2 instruction cycles per loop.  At 4 clock cycles per instruction cycle you've got 8 clock cycles.  The PIC18 has a 31 level stack, so after the 32nd loop it will overflow the stack, in 256 clock cycles.  At 64MHz, you would **overflow the stack in 4 micro seconds and 2 bytes**.

### PIC16F5x (even smaller and faster)

However, the PIC16F5x series uses 12 bit instructions:

```
CALL $
1001 0000 0000
```

Again, two instruction cycles per loop, 4 clocks per instruction so 8 clock cycles per loop.

However, the PIC16F5x has a two level stack, so on the third loop it would overflow, in 24 instructions.  At 20MHz, it would **overflow in 1.2 micro seconds and 1.5 bytes**.

### Intel 4004

The [Intel 4004](http://download.intel.com/museum/archives/pdf/4004_datasheet.pdf) has an 8 bit call subroutine instruction:

```
CALL $
0101 0000
```

For the curious that corresponds to an ascii 'P'.  With a 3 level stack that takes 24 clock cycles for a total of **32.4 micro seconds and one byte**.  (Unless you overclock your 4004 - come on, you know you want to.)

Which is as small as the befunge answer, but much, much faster than the befunge code running in current interpreters.

Answer (score 77):

C#:

```
public int Foo { get { return Foo; } }
```

Answer (score 57):

Hoot overflow!

```
//              v___v
let rec f o = f(o);(o)
//             ['---']
//             -"---"-
```

Answer (score 55):

Every task needs the right tool. Meet the [SO Overflow](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/krudolph/stuff/so/) language, optimized to produce stack overflows:

```
so
```

Comment: If you're making a specialized language for generating overflows with a minimal of code, obviously you would want (1) empty input produces stack overflowing code (probably a small binary that runs the native code generated from the assembly code entry) or (2) all input programs produce said binary.

Comment: Hmmm, not Turing complete.  I don't know if you could call it a language just yet...

Answer (score 42):

TeX:

```
\def~{~.}~
```

Results in:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
~->~
    .
~->~
    .
~->~
    .
~->~
    .
~->~
    .
~->~
    .
...
<*> \def~{~.}~
```

LaTeX:

```
\end\end
```

Results in:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\end #1->\csname end#1
                      \endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
<*> \end\end
```

Comment: Since `~` is active, it can be used in place of `\a`. And I discovered the LaTeX code completely by accident. :)

Answer (score 35):

Z-80 assembler -- at memory location 0x0000:

```
rst 00
```

one byte -- 0xC7 -- endless loop of pushing the current PC to the stack and jumping to address 0x0000.

Comment: I remember a blank eprom would be all 0xffs which are rst 7 (= call 0x0038) instructions. That would be useful for debugging your hardware with an oscilloscope. The address bus would cycle through the 64K space as the stack overflowed repeatedly, interspersed with reads of 0xff from 0x0038.

Answer (score 29):

In english:

```
recursion = n. See recursion.
```

Comment: Any sensible human brain will tail-call optimise the interpretation of this one too, and not blow up. :-P

Comment: Chris, sensible human brains are becoming a rarity these days.

Comment: rarity...you mean they exist?

Comment: Google recursion

Answer (score 29):

Another PHP Example:

```
<?
require(__FILE__);
```

Comment: You could even be shorted by skipping the parenthesis (but including  space in place of the first).

Answer (score 26):

How about the following in BASIC:

```
10 GOSUB 10
```

(I don't have a BASIC interpreter I'm afraid so that's a guess).

Comment: Not really a stack overflow since BASIC is a stackless language.  Even VB (which does have a stack) wouldn't overflow on this since it's just jumping, not creating a stack frame.

Comment: That's a `GOSUB`, not a `GOTO`. Since it `RETURN`s to where it was called from, surely it's using a stack?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I had *many* stack overflows in BASIC in the 80s.

Comment: I ran this one in yabasic just for the fun of it, and it nearly took down my computer.  Thank god malloc eventually failed, but I was paging like no tomorrow.

Comment: Oops sorry Adam... reminds me of a time at uni when someone accidentally wrote a program that recursively forked: took down an entire Silicon Graphics server.

Comment: Just tested it on my VZ200 emulator

?OUT OF MEMORY ERROR IN 10

Comment: WTF is anyone doing with a VZ200 emulator? :-) I don't pine for my old ZX80 or COMX-35.

Answer (score 26):

I loved Cody's answer heaps, so here is my similar contribution, in C++:

```
template <int i>
class Overflow {
    typedef typename Overflow<i + 1>::type type;
};

typedef Overflow<0>::type Kaboom;
```

Not a code golf entry by any means, but still, anything for a meta stack overflow! :-P

Answer (score 21):

Here's my C contribution, weighing in at 18 characters:

```
void o(){o();o();}
```

This is a *lot* harder to tail-call optimise! :-P

Comment: Doesn't compile for me: "undefined reference to `main'" :P

Comment: I don't understand: why call o() 2x?

Comment: @Dinah: One of the constraints of my contest was that tail-call optimisation doesn't count as recursion; it's just an iterative loop. If you only wrote o() once, that can be tail-call optimised into something like this (by a competent compiler): "o: jmp o". With 2 calls of o, the compiler has to use something like: "o: call o; jmp o". It's the recursive "call" instruction that makes the stack overflow.

Comment: You're correct -- I didn't pay attention to that part. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 19):

Using a Window's batch file named "s.bat":

```
call s
```

Answer (score 17):

**Javascript**

To trim a few more characters, and to get ourselves kicked out of more software shops, let's go with:

```
eval(i='eval(i)');
```

Answer (score 15):

Groovy:

```
main()
```

$ groovy stack.groovy:

```
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at stack.main(stack.groovy)
    at stack.run(stack.groovy:1)
 ...
```

Comment: Voted up because it's pretty interesting.  Exposes a rather annoying weakness in the Groovy compiler though (such tail-calls can be inlined at compile-time).

Comment: are you sure it's a tail call?  that falling off the end of the program doesn't invoke the interpreter shell?

Answer (score 15):

Please tell me what the acronym "[GNU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU)" stands for.

Comment: Or Eine (Eine is not Emacs), or Zwei (Zwei was Eine initially). :-P

Comment: Or YAML, or WINE, or XNA, or any of the rest at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym

Comment: Drei (Drei is Really Emacs Incognito), Fier (Fier is Emacs Reinvented) - ok so I just made those up :-)

Answer (score 14):

```
Person JeffAtwood;
Person JoelSpolsky;
JeffAtwood.TalkTo(JoelSpolsky);
```

Here's hoping for no tail recursion!

Comment: Hehe, funny. Related to conversations, the idea of the "echo chamber effect" is quite interesting, too. Not quite stack overflow-inducing, but still.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a null pointer exception? Sorry, I know it's a joke.

Answer (score 12):

**C** - It's not the shortest, but it's recursion-free. It's also not portable: it crashes on Solaris, but some alloca() implementations might return an error here (or call malloc()). The call to printf() is necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct rlimit rl = {0};
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
    (void) alloca(rl.rlim_cur);
    printf("Goodbye, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also just do "ulimit -s16" to set the stack really small.  Any smaller than about 16 and the program doesn't even run (insufficient args apparently!).

Answer (score 11):

**Python**:

```
so=lambda:so();so()
```

Alternatively:

```
def so():so()
so()
```

And if Python optimized tail calls...:

```
o=lambda:map(o,o());o()
```

Comment: Lucky for you, Python doesn't do tail-call optimisation; otherwise, it'd be disqualified like two other answers so far. :-P

Answer (score 11):

perl in 12 chars:

```
$_=sub{&$_};&$_
```

bash in 10 chars (the space in the function is important):

```
i(){ i;};i
```

Answer (score 11):

try and put more than 4 patties on a single burger. stack overflow.

Comment: Here in New Zealand we have Burger Wisconsin, where they use big but thin patties. I'm sure you can stack more than 4 of those if you want to; it'll be a very expensive burger though!

Comment: Maybe: http://www.alafista.com/2010/05/10/lotteria-tower-cheese-burger-with-10-patties/ Maybe not: http://cheaplightning.blogspot.com/2010/06/lotteria-10-patty-burger-bloody-history.html

Comment: Mmm... In-n-Out.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-n-out#Menu

Answer (score 10):

I'm selecting the “best answer” after this post. But first, I'd like to acknowledge some very original contributions:

1. aku's ones. Each one explores a new and original way of causing stack overflow. The idea of doing f(x) ⇒ f(f(x)) is one I'll explore in my next entry, below. :-)
2. Cody's one that gave the Nemerle *compiler* a stack overflow.
3. And (a bit grudgingly), GateKiller's one about throwing a stack overflow exception. :-P

Much as I love the above, the challenge is about doing code golf, and to be fair to respondents, I have to award “best answer” to the shortest code, which is the Befunge entry; I don't believe anybody will be able to beat that (although Konrad has certainly tried), so congrats Patrick!

Seeing the large number of stack-overflow-by-recursion solutions, I'm surprised that nobody has (as of current writing) brought up the Y combinator (see Dick Gabriel's essay, [The Why of Y](http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/WhyOfY.pdf), for a primer). I have a recursive solution that uses the Y combinator, as well as aku's f(f(x)) approach. :-)

```
((Y (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f (f x))))) #f)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's another interesting one from Scheme:

```
((lambda (x) (x x)) (lambda (x) (x x)))
```

Comment: Very nice, and there's a good symmetry to it too. Also, to use the (lambda (x) (x x)) formulation: ((Y (lambda (x) (x x))) #f) is a lot of fun too!

Comment: Oh, that's pretty.  It works in Ruby, too, although not as pretty as in Scheme: lambda { |x| x.call x }.call lambda { |x| x.call x }

Answer (score 7):

Java

Slightly shorter version of the Java solution.

```
class X{public static void main(String[]a){main(a);}}
```

Comment: Or (same number of characters): public static void main(String...a){main();}

Comment: Or for the TDD guys (same number of chars): public class ${@org.junit.Test public void $(){$();}}

Comment: Still not the shortest though (see my answer)

Answer (score 6):

```
xor esp, esp
ret
```

Comment: that's not really a stack overflow, but it's nice eitherwy :D

Answer (score 5):

3 bytes:

`label:
  pusha
  jmp label`

**Update**

According to [the (old?) Intel(?) documentation](http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/c.html#CALL), this is also 3 bytes:

`label:
  call label`

Comment: It's 3 bytes in 32-bit mode. Nice answer, considering it'll fill the stack much faster than my answer!

Comment: According to http://www.penguin.cz/~literakl/intel/j.html#JMP, jmp is 3 bytes with 8, 16 or 32 bit relative destination address. The pusha is also 1 bytes, which makes a total of 4

Comment: There are three types of jmp, short, near, and far. Short jmp (using 0xEB opcode) is two bytes. Destination must be between -128 and 127 bytes away from the next instruction. :-)

Comment: Maybe you're right. I'm too lazy to dig out my assembler and verify... ;)

Answer (score 4):

**Java** (embarassing):

```
public class SO 
{ 
  private void killme()
  {
    killme();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    new SO().killme(); 
  } 
}
```

**EDIT**
Of course it can be considerably shortened:

```
class SO
{
  public static void main(String[] a)
  {
    main(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Lua:

```
function f()return 1+f()end f()
```

You've got to do something to the result of the recursive call, or else tail call optimization will allow it to loop forever. Weak for code golf, but nice to have!

I guess that and the lengthy keywords mean Lua won't be winning the code golf anytime soon.

Comment: Ah.  You beat my (unpublished) score.  I used f()*f() to avoid the tail call.

Comment: The f()*f() isn't a bad idea, however: apparently (this isn't about Lua anymore BTW) GCC can tail-call optimise 1+f() too, on the premise that f() isn't expected to return, or something. See the comments on #62221 for more details. :-P

Answer (score 4):

Forth:

```
: a 1 recurse ; a
```

Inside the `gforth` interpreter:

```
: a 1 recurse ; a 
*the terminal*:1: Return stack overflow
: a 1 recurse ; a
                ^
Backtrace:
```

On a Power Mac G4 at the Open Firmware prompt, this just hangs the machine. :)

Answer (score 4):

as a local variable in a C function:

```
int x[100000000000];
```

Comment: Hex Encode the number to shorten this...

Answer (score 4):

http://www.google.com/search?q=google.com

Answer (score 3):

Ruby:

```
def s() s() end; s()
```

Comment: You call yourself a ruby programmer...? You can do better: def s;s;end;s

Answer (score 3):

GWBASIC output...

```
OK
10 i=0
20 print i;
30 i=i+1
40 gosub 20
run
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
 22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33
Out of memory in 30
Ok
```

Not much stack depth there :-)

Answer (score 3):

batch program called call.cmd;

call call.cmd

```
******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=1240, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
```

Answer (score 3):

In Scheme, this will cause the interpreter to run out of memory:

```
(define (x)
  ((x)))

(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby, shorter than the other ones so far:

```
def a;a;end;a
```

(13 chars)

Answer (score 3):

**C#**

```
class _{static void Main(){Main();}}
```

Note that mine is a compilable program, not just a single function.  I also removed excess whitespace.

For flair, I made the class name as small as I could.

Comment: You could even rename Main if you were willing to require a special command-line option to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider a call frame to be a process, and the stack to be your Unix machine, you could consider a fork bomb to be a *parallel* program to create a stack overflow condition.  Try this 13-character bash number.  No saving to a file is necessary.

```
:(){ :|:& };:
```

Answer (score 3):

In Irssi (terminal based IRC client, not "really" a programming language), $L means the current command line. So you can cause a stack overflow ("hit maximum recursion limit") with:

```
/eval $L
```

Answer (score 2):

PIC18:

> overflow
>
> > ```
> >     PUSH   
> >     CALL   overflow
> > ```

Comment: Very nice, similar in spirit to my answer. How many bytes of object code does it create?

Comment: To be honest I'm not really too sure!

Answer (score 2):

**CIL/MSIL**:

```
loop: ldc.i4.0
br loop
```

Object code:

```
16 2B FD
```

Comment: Hmm, will the .NET verifier accept that? For JVM, you have to specify the maximum stack usage, and the verifier will enforce it, so code like the above (iconst_0; goto loop) will get rejected.

Answer (score 2):

**Lisp**

```
(defun x() (x)) (x)
```

Comment: With some compiler flags, this can also be tail-call optimised. :-)

Comment: In current implementations of Common Lisp, you will have to explicitly declaim or declare TCO away.  Scheme even requires TCO.  To make this surely overflow, don't tail recurse:  (defun x () (1+ (x))) (x).

Answer (score 2):

```
a{return a*a;};
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -D"a=main()" so.c
```

Expands to:

```
main() {
    return main()*main();
}
```

Comment: Eh, with Perl golf at least, command-line options count towards the character count. :-P

Comment: OK 26 chars, included command-line option, for a completely compilable and runnable program.

Comment: Okay, fine, I'll let you have this one, since you wanted a version with main. :-)

Answer (score 2):

F#

People keep asking "What is F# useful for?"

```
let rec f n =
    f (n)
```

performance optimized version (will fail faster :) )

```
let rec f n =
    f (f(n))
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, fails with 'error FS0030: Value restriction' for me.

Comment: Use their latest CTP, works for me :) also try f(f(n))

Comment: hm, it might have been fixed in the 1.9.6.0 -> 1.9.6.2 release I guess then, will go check it out :-)

Comment: The first one is tail recursive, the second one will work though

Answer (score 2):

In Whitespace, I think:

It probably won't show up. :/

Comment: Browsers won't show tabs very well to begin with, and Markdown just completely obliterates it. I'll paste in what I can see (editing privileges for the win!) in my next comment.

Comment: SP SP SP TAB NL NL
SP SP SP TAB SP SP SP SP TAB TAB NL
TAB SP SP SP NL
SP TAB SP TAB SP SP SP SP TAB TAB NL NL NL

Answer (score 2):

Haskell:

```
let x = x
print x
```

Comment: That's not a stack overflow. `let f x = f x >> x in f $ return()`

Answer (score 2):

Well, nobody's mentioned Coldfusion yet, so...

```
<cfinclude template="#ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME, "/\")#">
```

That oughta do it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's a language where the empty program causes a stack overflow, the following should be the shortest possible.

Befunge:

```
:
```

Duplicates the top stack value over and over again.

edit:
 Patrick's is better.  Filling the stack with 1s is better than filling the stack with 0s, since the interpreter could optimize pushing 0s onto an empty stack as a no-op.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy (5B):

```
run()
```

Answer (score 2):

C#

```
class Program
{
    class StackOverflowExceptionOverflow : System.Exception
    {
        public StackOverflowExceptionOverflow()
        {
            throw new StackOverflowExceptionOverflow();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw new StackOverflowExceptionOverflow();
    }
}
```

I realize this is not the shortest (and even code golfed it would not come close to be anywhere near short), but I simply could not resist throwing an exception that while being thrown throws a stackoverflowexception, before it is able to terminate the runtime itself ^^

Answer (score 2):

## PostScript, 7 characters

```
{/}loop
```

When run in GhostScript, throws this exception:

```
GS>{/}loop
Error: /stackoverflow in --execute--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   1753   2   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1150/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 11
Current file position is 8
```

Here's the recursive version without using variables (51 chars):

```
[{/[aload 8 1 roll]cvx exec}aload 8 1 roll]cvx exec
```

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
class X{static{new X();}{new X();}}
```

Actually causes a stack overflow initializing the X class. Before main() is called, the JVM must load the class, and when it does so it triggers any anonymous static code blocks:

```
static {
  new X();
}
```

Which as you can see, instantiates X using the default constructor. The JVM will call anonymous code blocks even before the constructor:

```
{
  new X();
}
```

Which is the recursive part.

Answer (score 2):

**Java: 35 characters**

I think it's too late, but I will still post my idea:

```
class A{{new A();}static{new A();}}
```

Using the static initializer and instance initializer features.

Here is the output on my computer (notice it showed two error messages):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at A.<init>(A.java:1)
        ......
    at A.<init>(A.java:1)
Could not find the main class: A. Program will exit.
```

See also: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Although your answer is still longer than the winning answer :-), it's still a pretty neat approach, so +1 to you!

Comment: At last, I realized someone else did it first. It's on about the middle pages where it's very hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

## C++ Compiler Error Message

```
template<int n>struct f{f<n+1>a;};f<0>::a;
```

output:

```
$ g++ test.cpp;
test.cpp:1: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 500 (use -ftemplate-depth-NN to increase the maximum) instantiating ‘struct f<500>’
test.cpp:1:   instantiated from ‘f<499>’
test.cpp:1:   instantiated from ‘f<498>’
......
```

Even if the compiler went through the template, there will be the next error: missing `main`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* In C/C++ (second attempt) */

int main(){
    int a = main() + 1;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Much better! I have my own little contribution coming up, too. :-P

Comment: It seems that this can be optimised too.  with gcc -O3, it just runs and runs.

Comment: Nice, Andrew; it did get optimised to a jump too!

Comment: haha in C++ you cannot call main nor take its address :p

Comment: @litb - you say this like it's a benefit.

Answer (score 1):

c# again:

```
class Foo { public Foo() {new Foo(); } }
```

Comment: Another excellent one, keep up the good work!

Comment: Would changing the class into a struct not use even more stack space since a struct is value type?

Answer (score 1):

Complete Delphi program.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;

begin
  raise EStackOverflow.Create('Stack Overflow');
end.
```

Comment: Oi, this is only funny once, and GateKiller had that answer already. :-P

Answer (score 1):

so.c in **15 characters**:

```
main(){main();}
```

Result:

```
antti@blah:~$ gcc so.c -o so
antti@blah:~$ ./so
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Edit**: Okay, it gives warnings with -Wall and does not cause a stack overflow with -O2. But it works!

Comment: Blech! That's undefined, because you have an implicit int return, with no actual return value. If you declared main as void (for some reason), then tail call optimisation can apply. So, nope. :-P

Answer (score 1):

**JavaSript:**

Huppies answer to one line:

```
(function i(){ i(); })()
```

Same amount of characters, but no new line :)

Comment: This is kind of clever, because lack of TCO is a known 'feature' of many JavaScript engines.

Comment: +1 `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 1):

Java (complete content of X.java):

```
class X {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main(null);
}}
```

Considering all the syntactic sugar, I am wondering if any shorter can be done in Java. Anyone?

**EDIT:** Oops, I missed there is already almost identical solution posted.

**EDIT 2:** I would say, that this one is (character wise) the shortest possible

```
class X{public static void main(String[]a){main(null);}}
```

**EDIT 3:** Thanks to Anders for pointing out null is not optimal argument, so it's shorter to do:

```
class X{public static void main(String[]a){main(a);}}
```

Comment: class X{public static void main(String[]a){main("");}} is shorter... ;)

Comment: @Anders: "" instanceof String[] => false

Comment: Nope, I've done shorter - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was a perl one already, but this is a couple characters shorter (9 vs 12) - and it doesn't recurse :)

> s//*_=0/e

Comment: Nice! That's clever. But it doesn't work in 5.10: 
    $> perl -e's//*_=0/e'
    perl(30740) malloc: *** error for object 0x301070: double free *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: Same error here on my Perl 5.8.8. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I have a list of these at [Infinite Loop](http://www.everything2.com/index.pl?node_id=1904026) on E2 - see just the ones indicated as "Stack Overflow" in the title.

I think the shortest there is

```
[dx]dx
```

in [dc](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DeeCee). There may be a shorter solution in [False](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FalseLanguage).

EDIT: Apparently this doesn't work... At least on GNU dc. Maybe it was on a BSD version.

Comment: It doesn't work. dc consumes 100% CPU but not stack overflow in dc (GNU bc 1.06.94) 1.3.94 occured. dc -e '[dx+]dx' makes Segmentation fault.

Comment: Hmm... I was sure it worked on some version. It may only be on some BSD version.

Answer (score 1):

Shell script solution in **10 characters** including newlines:

Well, technically not stack overflow but logically so, if you consider spawning a new process as constructing a new stack frame.

```
#!sh
./so
```

Result:

```
antti@blah:~$ ./so
[disconnected]
```

Whoops. Note: **don't try this at home**

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell**

> $f={&$f};&$f

"The script failed due to call depth overflow.  The call depth reached 1001 and the maximum is 1000."

Answer (score 1):

In assembly language (x86 processors, 16 or 32 bit mode):

```
call $
```

which will generate:

- in 32 bit mode: 0xe8;0xfb;0xff;0xff;0xff
- in 16 bit mode: 0xe8;0xfd;0xff

in C/C++:

```
int main( ) {
  return main( );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TCL:

```
proc a {} a
```

I don't have a tclsh interpreter that can do tail recursion, but this might fool such a thing:

```
proc a {} "a;a"
```

Answer (score 1):

won't be the shortest but I had to try something... C#

string[] f = new string[0]; Main(f);

bit shorter

```
static void Main(){Main();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Ruby answer, this one uses lambdas:

```
(a=lambda{a.call}).call
```

Comment: Took only a split second to get "... 22730 levels..." in the "stack level too deep" error I get.

Answer (score 1):

Another one in **JavaScript**:

```
(function() { arguments.callee() })()
```

Comment: Nice, I like this one because, like my Y combinator version, it doesn't require you to give a name to the function. Good stuff!

Comment: `(function(){arguments.callee()})()`

Comment: function x(){x()}x() -> 20; 
function x()x();x()  -> 19, only works in Firefox; 
Nice try tough ;P (jk)

Answer (score 1):

Vb6

```
Public Property Let x(ByVal y As Long)
  x = y
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  x = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. Similar theme to one of aku's solutions (except there it was a property getter, and here it's a property setter). +1!

Answer (score 1):

Short solution in K&R C, could be compiled:

```
main(){main()}
```

14 bytes

Answer (score 1):

In response to the Y combinator comment, i might as well through in the Y-combinator in the SKI calculus:

```
S (K (S I I)) (S (S (K S) K) (K (S I I)))
```

There aren't any SKI interpreters that i know of but i once wrote a graphical one in about an hour in actionscript. I would be willing to post if there is interest (though i never got the layout working very efficiently)

read all about it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus

Answer (score 1):

in perl:

```
`$0`
```

As a matter of fact, this will work with any shell that supports the backquote-command syntax and stores its own name in `$0`

Comment: Or, perhaps, "do $0"? *goes and tries*

Comment: I was going to leave your answer be, however, you've edited it enough times that I should speak. :-P What some posters have mentioned is that this is more a process-table overflow, than a stack overflow as such. Some people have posted fork bombs in this thread too, which may interest you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

False:

[1][1]#

(False is a stack language: # is a while loop that takes 2 closures, a conditional and a body. The body is the one that causes the overflow).

Answer (score 1):

CMD overflow in one line

```
echo @call b.cmd > b.cmd & b
```

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell

```
fix (1+)
```

This tries to find the fix point of the (1+) function (`λ n → n + 1`) .  The implementation of fix is

```
fix f = (let x = f(x) in x)
```

So

```
fix (1+)
```

becomes

```
(1+) ((1+) ((1+) ...))
```

Note that

```
fix (+1)
```

just loops.

Answer (score 1):

**A better lua solution:**

```
function c()c()end;
```

Stick this into SciTE or an interactive command prompt and then call it. Boom!

Answer (score 1):

GNU make:

Create a file called "Makefile" with the following contents:

```
a:
    make
```

Then run make:

```
$ make
```

Note that a tab character must be used to offset the word "make".  This file is 9 characters, including the 2 end-of-line characters and the 1 tab character.

I suppose you could do a similar thing with bash, but it's probably too easy to be interesting:

Create a filename "b" and mark it as executable (chmod +x b):

```
b ## ties the winning entry with only one character (does not require end-of-line)
```

Now execute the file with

```
$ ( PATH=$PATH:. ; b )
```

It's hard to say whether this approach technically results in stack overflow, but it does build a stack which will grow until the machine runs out of resources.  The cool thing about doing it with GNU make is that you can watch it output status information as it builds and destroys the stack (assuming you hit ^C at some point before the crash occurs).

Answer (score 1):

[PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php) is a recursive acronym

Answer (score 0):

**C++**:

```
int overflow(int n)
{
    return overflow(1);
}
```

Comment: A good compiler can tail-call optimise that one! :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    int a = 20;
    return main();
}
```

Comment: Like Niyaz's answer, this can also be tail-call optimised too!

Comment: This is invalid code, according to C++98 3.6.1.3 "The function main shall not be used within a program". </language_nazi>

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript:**

```
function i(){ i(); }
i();
```

---

**C++**
Using a function-pointer:

```
int main(){
   int (*f)() = &main;
   f();
}
```

Comment: @danb, I did try that but Rhino didn't want to compile it.

Comment: new function i(){i()}(); works. still not shorter of course...

Comment: As I commented in the comment to Vulcan Eager's post the C++ version is invalid, according to C++98 3.6.1.3 "The function main shall not be used within a program". </language_nazi>

Comment: @Motti: Shame on Microsoft for compiling it just fine without errors in VS8 ;-)

Comment: @Huppie - i'd venture to guess that this is a no-diagnostic-required error, much as is stack overflows to begin with.  !(code compiling -> code correct).

Answer (score 0):

C#, done in 20 characters (exclusing whitespace):

```
int s(){
    return s();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this one of a (small) number of circumstances where the .NET JIT compiler can tail-call optimise? :-P

Comment: I have no idea, but it crashed my development web server :)

Answer (score 0):

Clarion:

```
Poke(0)
```

Comment: Is there any publicly available documentation on how Clarion works?

Comment: www.softvelocity.com has a fair amount of information, and the Clarion public newsgroup (comp.lang.clarion) has a wealth of information and an active community (although the newsgroup on news.softvelocity.com is the primary group and doesn't seem to be typically be synchronized with other servers).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it in Erlang:

```
c(N)->c(N+1)+c(N-1).
c(0).
```

The double invocation of itself makes the memory usage go up `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n)`.

However the Erlang interpreter doesn't appear to manage to crash.

Comment: Does c(N)->c(N+1)+c(N+1) work?

Answer (score 0):

recursion is old hat.  here is mutual recursion.  kick off by calling either function.

```
a()
{
    b();
}
b()
{
    a();
}
```

PS: but you were asking for shortest way.. not most creative way!

Comment: Which language is this? If it's a dynamic language, then tail-call optimisation can apply; if it's C, and you're relying on implicit int, the lack of a return value is undefined behaviour. Using "return a()" and "return b()" would also be subject to tail call optimisation. :-P

Answer (score 0):

On the cell spus, there are no stack overflows, so theres no need for recursion, we can just wipe the stack pointer.

asm("andi $1, $1, 0" );

Answer (score 0):

**PHP** - recursion just for fun.  I imagine needing a PHP interpreter takes it out of the running, but hey - it'll make the crash.

```
function a() { a(); } a();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//lang = C++... it's joke, of course
//Pay attention how 
void StackOverflow(){printf("StackOverflow!");}
int main()
{
    StackOverflow(); //called StackOverflow, right?
}
```

Comment: *rimshot* - He'll be here all week, try the veal.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl** in 10 chars

```
sub x{&x}x
```

Eventually uses up all available memory.

Answer (score 0):

**MS-DOS batch:**

```
copy CON so.bat
so.bat
^Z
so.bat
```

Comment: Wait, you have to say "Call so.bat". Running a batch file without call is like using exec, if I remember right. :-P

Answer (score 0):

C# with 27 non-whitespace characters - includes the call.

```
Action a = null;
a = () => a();
a();
```

Answer (score 0):

**bash:** Only one process

```
\#!/bin/bash
of() { of; }
of
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any shell:

```
sh $0
```

(5 characters, only works if run from file)

Comment: sh $0& sh $0; # system crash (stop it with kill -9 -1 in another shell as the same user)

Answer (score 0):

Five bytes in 16-bit asm which will cause a stack overflow.

```
push cs
push $-1
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net

```
Function StackOverflow() As Integer
    Return StackOverflow()
End Function
```

Comment: Under certain conditions, I'm given to understand that the .NET JIT compiler can tail-call optimise that one!

Answer (score 0):

For Fun I had to look up the Motorolla HC11 Assembly:

```
              org           $100
Loop    nop
          jsr            Loop
```

Comment: Hmm, does the HC11 not allow you to jsr straight away? Why is the nop necessary?

Comment: Your right.  I was simply being lazy ;-)  Existed too long in the higher level languages.  Time to get back to the low low level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Not very short, but effective! (JavaScript)

```
setTimeout(1, function() {while(1) a=1;});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cheating I've never played before ;) but here goes

8086 assembler:

org Int3VectorAdrress ;is that cheating?

int 3

1 byte - or 5 characters that generate code, what say you?

Comment: Hahaha, nice try. I think to get away with this, you'd have to set the int 3 vector address to something suitable first, and that'd cost you some code bytes too. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Ruby, albeit not that short:

```
class Overflow
    def initialize
        Overflow.new
    end
end

Overflow.new
```

Answer (score 0):

In **C#**, this would create a stackoverflow...

```
static void Main()
{
    Main();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
mov sp,0
```

(stack grows down)

Answer (score 0):

In a **PostScript** file called so.ps will cause execstackoverflow

```
%!PS
/increase {1 add} def
1 increase
(so.ps) run
```

Comment: I think you meant to say this instead: /recurse {1 recurse} def recurse

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript 3: All done with arrays...

```
var i=[];
i[i.push(i)]=i;
trace(i);
```

Maybe not the smallest but I think it's cute. Especially the push method returning the new array length!

Comment: If you replace `trace(i);` with `console.log(i);` it's also valid JavaScript code in Chrome or Firefox with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

In x86 assembly, place a divide by 0 instruction at the location in memory of the interrupt handler for divide by 0!

Comment: I believe [this submission](#67749) uses the same concepts, but nice try anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Prolog**

This program crashes both SWI-Prolog and Sicstus Prolog when consulted.

```
p :- p, q.
:- p.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tail call optimization can be sabotaged by not tail calling. In Common Lisp:

```
(defun f () (1+ (f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta problem in D:

```
class C(int i) { C!(i+1) c; }
C!(1) c;
```

compile time stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
_asm t: call t;
```

Answer (score 0):

OCaml

```
let rec f l = f l@l;;
```

This one is a little different. There's only one stack frame on the stack (since it's tail recursive), but it's input keeps growing until it overflows the stack. Just call `f` with a non empty list like so (at the interpreter prompt):

```
# f [0];;
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it doesn't really have a stack...

**brainf*ck 5 char**

```
+[>+]
```

Answer (score 0):

Z80 assembly language...

```
.org 1000
loop: call loop
```

this generates 3 bytes of code at location 1000....

1000 CD 00 10

Answer (score 0):

ruby (again):

```
def a(x);x.gsub(/./){a$0};end;a"x"
```

There are plenty of ruby solutions already but I thought I'd throw in a regexp for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Another Windows Batch file:

```
:a
@call :a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main(){
   main();
}
```

Plain and nice C. Feels quite Intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

### Fortran, 13 and 20 chars

```
real n(0)
n(1)=0
end
```

or

```
call main
end
```

The second case is compiler-dependent; for GNU Fortran, it will need to be compiled with `-fno-underscoring`.

(Both counts include required newlines)

Answer (score 0):

Haskell:

```
main = print $ x 1 where x y = x y + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Dyalog APL

```
fib←{
    ⍵∊0 1:⍵
    +/∇¨⍵-1 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void) { return main(); }
```

Comment: Fail, your answer can be tail-call optimised. :-P (Compiler turns that effectively into `goto _main`, where `_main` is the global symbol corresponding to your main function.)

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import sys  
sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.maxint)  
def so():  
    so()  
so()
```

Comment: why sys.maxint, just set it to 1, crash it quicker...and save chars.

Comment: If i setrecursionlimit(1), it will raise a RuntimeError, not crash.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (17 Bytes)

```
eval(t="eval(t)")
```

### VB Script (25 Bytes)

```
t="Execute(t)":Execute(t)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ruby:

```
def i()i()end;i()
```

(17 chars)

Answer (score -1):

**Prolog**

p:-p.

= 5 characters

then start it and query p

i think that is quite small and runs out of stack in prolog.

a query of just a variable in swi prolog produces:

?- X.
% ... 1,000,000 ............ 10,000,000 years later
% 
%       >> 42 << (last release gives the question)

and here is another bash fork bomb:
:(){ :|:& };:

Comment: It doesn't run out of stack, at least in SWI-Prolog. It's tail recursion. What does run out of stack is: "assert(p :- (p, q)), assert(q). p."

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work in Java (untried):

```
enum A{B.values()}
enum B{A.values()}
```

Should overflow in static initialization before it even gets the chance to fail due to a lack of main(String[]).

Answer (score -4):

```
Redmond.Microsoft.Core.Windows.Start()
```