# How to produce a StackOverflowException with a few lines of code?

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow

How can I produce a `StackOverflowException` with minimal lines of code?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188/stack-overflow-code-golf

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like this:

```
A() { new A(); }
```

Comment: One line, but fewer characters and produces a *real* exception... +1 (does it not need a `void` return in C# though?)

Comment: @BoltClock: It's a constructor.

Comment: Ah OK. I see you just added the `new`.

Comment: agree, can you explain a little whats happening here, im new to .net and all this jargons.

Comment: @aGuy: It's a constructor that calls itself.  A slightly longer, but clearer, version would be `int A() { return A(); }`.

Comment: @aGuy: Basically you have a class with a constructor that makes a new object of the same class. So essentially it's a constructor calling itself recursively.

Comment: In Java, you can call another (or presumably the same) constructor with a `this` call. So you get `A() { this(); }` which reduces a character. Is this doable in C#?

Answer (score 41):

```
throw new StackOverflowException();
```

Cheating, I know... :)

Comment: this is the simplest way to generate any kind of exceptions for testing

Comment: Jajaja... i was thinking in something "a little more elaborated", but it works too..

Comment: @kinjal For this specific exception it's going to be hard to test - you cannot catch a StackOverflowException.

Comment: @chibacity: `try { throw new StackOverflowException(); } catch (StackOverflowException ex) { Console.WriteLine("Yes you can."); }` (sorry, I know it's getting old :)

Comment: @BoltClock Well I'll be jiggered. You are quite correct. It must be only when it is generated via the OS and it is treated as an exception of doom i.e. an application flattener.

Comment: @chibacity: Of course, it'll be an inevitable crash at that point.

Comment: @BoltClock Well to be precise, the fact that it is treated as fatal is a design choice in the .Net framework. In .Net 1.0 you could catch and ignore a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 18):

Not the shortest one but funny:)

```
public static bool IsNotEmpty(string value)
{
    return !IsEmpty(value);
}

public static bool IsEmpty(string value)
{
    return !IsNotEmpty(value);
}

public static void Main()
{
    bool empty = IsEmpty("Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void Main()
{
  Main();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I always use this code (because it is harder to detect)  :-(

```
private int _num;
public int Num {
   get { return Num; }
   set { _num = value; }
}
```

Comment: It would be even better if the field name was `num` (without the underscore prefix). ;)

Answer (score 3):

in pseudocode

```
func(): call func()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int Method(int i)
{
  return i + Method(i + 1);
}
```

I think this should work. In general, any recursion that doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Run this code (recursion):

```
f () {
       f();
    }
```